# Knockout 2.3 radiogroup retrieve selected value

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

The thing that I am trying to solve is this: a radiolist is filled by parsing an array of json objects after a jquery onclick event. I have bound a knockout property when there is a checked option, but that only puts the name of the current selected option in the observable. I'd like to fill `shipOption` with the name (which works now) but also wants the value of the costs in `shipCost`. The formatcurrency is just a helper function to display it user friendly.

My Knockout and js code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var shipOptions = [];

    function ovm() {
        var self = this;
        self.shippingOptions = ko.observableArray(shipOptions);
        self.shipOption = ko.observable();
        self.shipCost = ko.observable();
    }
    window.vm = new ovm();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

My HTML:

```
<table style="width: 60%;" data-bind="foreach: shippingOptions">
    <tr>
        <td><label><input name="shipmentoptions" type="radio" data-bind="value: Name, checked: $parent.shipOption" /><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></label></td>
        <td>&euro; <span data-bind="text: formatCurrency(Costs())"></span></td>
        <td><img data-bind="attr: { src: Picture }"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

p.s. I use knockout 2.3 and I use the mapping plugin to fill the json objects in the shipoptions array

Comment: You can make your `self.shipCost` to a computed where you lookup the cost based on the currently selected name. Something like `self.shipCost = ko.computed(function() { var item = findInArrayByName(seld.shipOption()); return item.cost });`

Comment: Also, `ovm()` isn't written correctly for use with `new`; it sets a global variable called `self` and then doesn't return anything. Either start it off with `var self=this;` and then use it with `new` or start it with `var self={};`, end it with `return self;` and then don't use `new`.

Comment: @ebohlman I am sorry, I forgot to copy paste the line `var self = this;` I have edited the question and managed to fix it with the comment of nemesv and yours.